# How do you submit a support request on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I used to submit ticket requests, but can't find a link to submit. Did they remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Search for your issue on https://help.heroku.com/
2. If the search results don't help, there's a link at the bottom of the results page to open a ticket.

Comment: Heroku, It shouldn't be that hard to find that we go to StackOverflow.